# Using variables in SQL to cross-reference two databases

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to cross-reference two databases, one is users who have signed up. And the other is call log from a phone server.

They have nothing in common, other than the phone number.

```
SELECT 

`pbx_operations`.`call_log`.`caller`,
`pbx_operations`.`call_log`.`call_start`,

`promo `.`promo_user_phone`.`number` AS n2,
`promo `.`promo_user_phone`.`prouid`

FROM `pbx_operations`.`call_log`

WHERE `pbx_operations`.`call_log`.`caller` LIKE '%n2%'
```

I can't `LEFT JOIN` them because the format of the number entered into the database and the format that comes from the operator/phone server can and do differ.

When I run the SQL above in phpMyAdmin, I get nothing...not even an error or null rows found. So I'm guessing it's incorrect.

---

Sample data:

**For `pbx_operations.call_log.caller`:**

0038160XXXXXX@IMS-MSS3002-BitNat-ctx

**For `promo.promo_user_phone.number`:**

60XXXXXX

---

**What I am trying to do is match the `60XXXXXX` inside `0038160XXXXXX@IMS-MSS3002-BitNat-ctx`**

I am unable to post an actual number, so the `X`'s are the rest of the number.

Comment: Please post sample data. I belive you want to refer to n2 column not to "n2" string

Comment: "pbx" suggests you won't have too many records for this to work, but if you do try to scale up, it's probably more efficient to parse it on entry and store the phone number in the same format in both tables for a more efficient join. Yes, this goes against the "normalization" they teach at school, it's actually called "denormalization".

Comment: @Szocske Theres plenty of records to match up against from the PBX. Just is there a way to do it without editing the incoming call format?

Comment: Sorry, Re-reading my comment it's quite ambiguous: In a PBX scenario you should not have scaling problems. The non-indexable answer should be adequate.

Comment: @Szocske I don't have any scaling problems...taking in the call records from my PBX server into a MySql DB. Just needed a reliable way to cross-reference users who have signed up for a certain promotion, and see if the same phone number has reached out via phone. That way I know they are interested in the product and I can implement additional advertising strategies to target those particular users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query should looks like:

```
SELECT 

`pbx_operations`.`call_log`.`caller`,
`pbx_operations`.`call_log`.`call_start`,

`promo `.`promo_user_phone`.`number` AS n2,
`promo `.`promo_user_phone`.`prouid`

FROM `pbx_operations`.`call_log`
JOIN `promo `.`promo_user_phone`.`number`
  ON `pbx_operations`.`call_log`.`caller` 
  LIKE CONCAT('%',`promo `.`promo_user_phone`.`number`,'%');
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/SCV59531)**

Second if numbers in both columns have different format then you need to normalize it. For example by removing everything except digits.

Comment: By different format I meant the country prefix. The numbers from `promo `.`promo_user_phone`.`number` don't have a prefix. And the `pbx_operations`.`call_log`.`caller` is recorded in the full format by the operator. Thats why I'm trying to compare the bare number with only the operator prefix, against a number in full format.

Comment: @Borsn Still I don't see a problem. If country prefix has defined format just omit first 3 or 4 characters.

Comment: I ran the code you provide above and it returns an error at line 10

Comment: @Borsn It is your code. Please look carefully for example `promo `. Do you really have space in name?

Comment: The error is thrown here `LIKE CONCAT()...`, is `JOIN` able to accept `LIKE`?

Comment: @Borsn Of course it could take any condition. **[Rextester.com demo](http://rextester.com/KKR78853)**

Comment: I've posted sample data, please take a look. Will your solution apply to the sample data?

Comment: @Borsn Please check my edit. If you want query that you just copy to your environment post table structures and data using **[REXTESTER.COM](http://rextester.com)**